Find angle $x$ in the triangle below
Find $x^o$ if $BC = 2AB$.
AD = AC
(Answer: $18^o 30'$)

I try:
AB = x, BC  =2x
$AC^2=AB^2+BC^2 \implies AC^2 = x^2+4x^2 \therefore AC = x\sqrt5$
$\triangle ABC: (x:2x:x\sqrt5) \implies (\frac{53^o}{2}:\frac{127^o}{2}:90^o)$
$\triangle ADC: \angle ADC \cong \angle ACD = 45^o $
How do I finish?

Would there be a geometric solution without using trigonometric formulas? As it is a question from a geometry book, they do not use these trigonometric formulas and work more with auxiliary lines and approximate notable right triangles... From the answer I imagine that they used the right triangle (k:3k:$k\sqrt10$)


Denote by $E$ the foot of perpendicular from $D$ to $AB$. The angles of the right triangles reveal $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle DEA$. Hence, we have $$|AE| = 2|DE| = 2|AB|.$$
For the angle $x$, this gives
$\begin{align}
\tan x &= \dfrac{|DE|}{|BE|} \\
&= \dfrac{|DE|}{|AB|+|AE|} \\
&= \dfrac{|AB|}{|AB|+2|AB|} \\
&= \dfrac13.
\end{align}$
Therefore, angle $x$ equals $$\boxed{ x=\arctan \dfrac13 \approx 18.435^\circ }.$$

Very good answer, I like it very much (+1).

Excellent..thanks

In $\triangle ADB$, applying sine rule we can write:
$$\frac {AB}{\sin ADB}=\frac {AD}{\sin ABD}=\frac {BD}{\sin BAD}$$
We know that $\angle ABD=y$ [since you have used $x$ already, I am changing the variable here], then we need to find $\angle ABD$ from here. Here, $AD=x\sqrt 5$, $AB=x$. To find $\angle ADB$, we can write that:
$$\angle ADB=180-y-\angle DAB=180-y-(90+\angle CAB)=90-y-\tan^{-1}2$$
Therefore, we can conclude:
$$\frac {1}{\sin (90-x-\tan^{-1}2)}=\frac {\sqrt5}{\sin x}$$
And hopefully find $x$ from here [I have then replaced $y$ with $x$ here again].
If I go further, I can write:
$$
\frac1{\sqrt 5}=\frac{cos(x+\tan^{-1}2)}{\sin x}
=\frac{\frac 1{\sqrt5}\cos x-\frac2{\sqrt5}\sin x}{\sin x}$$
$$1=\frac{\cos x-2\sin x}{\sin x}=\cot x-2\Rightarrow x=\cot^{-1}3=18^\circ26'5.82''$$

Thanks for help

I request you to accept it as an answer if it has helped you.

Thank you for the solution but I will wait to see if there is another more geometric solution. If it does not appear, I will accept it as defined but I have already marked it as a useful answer. These Peruvian questions do not use trigonometric formulas such as the sine theorem. They solve them basically through geometry with the help of auxiliary lines.


This figure shows how can one divide a line to three or six parts using straight edge and compass.
$NL=MN=KM$
In triangle DEH we have:
$PQ=\frac 13 EH$
$LN=2 PQ=\frac 23 EH=\frac 23\times \frac 12 AB=\frac13 AB$
$\angle ABD=tan^{-1}\frac 13$
